# Could some help analyze the structure of this sentence "Sleet is *rain and snow mixed together*"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

Consider this sentence

> Sleet is rain and snow mixed together.

I guess it is in the form of

```
subject + be (predicate) + object
```

I cannot understand the object part, namely, rain and snow mixed together.

Could some help analyze the structure of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure is usually analysed as "subject + "be" + complement.

The complement isn't an object, for example you can't turn this into a passive sentence.

So the subject is "sleet" and its complement is a noun phrase. "rain and snow mixed together". That noun phrase has a participle "mixed", which functions passively: the object of "mixed" is "rain and snow" (in passive participle phrases the grammatical subject is the logical object).  The word "together" is an adverb, which modifies the participle "mixed".

Comment: Thank you so much. I still cannot get a completely clear understanding due to the concept of **passive participle**, so I posted another [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239460/109190), would please take a loot at that?