# Is "still cannot" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

In another post ([Could some help analyze the structure of this sentence "Sleet is *rain and snow mixed together*"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239455/109190)) I said

> I **still cannot** get a completely clear understanding due to the concept of passive participle, so I posted another question, would please take a loot at that?

Is "still cannot" idiomatic? Does the sentence above sound natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "still cannot" seems perfectly idiomatic.

"Still" means "*up to and including the present or the time mentioned*". It implies that what is happening in the present is the same as has happened in the past.

If you simply said "I cannot understand this", it could mean that you only just attempted to understand it now. Saying "I *still* cannot understand this" implies that you have spent some considerable time attempting to understand it.